# Flash animation generated on demand by server

Tags: flash, animation, render

I have a big project ahead which main requirement is to generate a previously defined Flash animation but with different parameters, like text and images. This application would run inside a server for the sole purpose of generate SWF animations on demand by users themselves. I've found similar functionality in this website http://www.bannersnack.com.

Would be great if someone could give some pointers about what kind of libraries, SDK or tools should I learn besides Flash.

Comment: If the animation is static (does not change) then you would just have to create 1 swf, and load the images/text from externals.

Comment: yes, animation its static, what changes is animated text and posibly images or backgrounds.

Comment: I don't think you would need much else besides flash, since flash has the ability to read in data. There are multiple ways to do this: You could embed the flash inside an html page that contains the data, or use javascript to get the data, or write a script that flash can call itself to get the data, etc. It would more depend on how you want to make it.